# css3 animation inside owl carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I've made a simple css3 animation (progress bar) and tried to put it inside my owl carousel slider, more particularly, to the buttons.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
        navigation : true,
        pagination : true,
        paginationSpeed : 400,
        singleItem: true,
        transitionStyle: "mask",
        autoHeight: true,
        autoPlay: 6000, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds
        navigationText : false,
        afterAction : syncPosition,

        afterAction: function(current) {
        current.find('video').get(0).play();
    }


      });
          function syncPosition(el){
    var current = this.currentItem;      
    // code for smooth transition
    this.owl.owlItems.removeClass('turn-on');
    $(this.owl.owlItems[this.owl.currentItem]).addClass('turn-on');
  }
      function top_align() {
        $(window).scrollTop(0);
        console.log('move');
      }



    });
```

When it detect currentItem (visible slider) it turn the class (turn-on) and starts animation.

The problem is that the progress-bar animation, but also transitionStyle: "mask" doesn't work with the script below which I use to start the video in the slider.  Of course when I remove it, it works fine.

```
afterAction: function(current) {
    current.find('video').get(0).play();
}
```

UPDATE: Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EGrGN/1052/)

Do have someone an idea how to solve it? Thx in advance.

Comment: Would you please create an example of this issue in CODEPEN.io or JASFIDDLE.net?

Comment: @zero-point I've got it http://jsfiddle.net/EGrGN/1046/